# Understanding AJAX JSON POST response in WordPress function

Tags: php, jquery, json, wordpress, post

I am testing ajax in WordPress for the first time. I want to send an ID and a string using 'POST' when users click on a button. I need the value of the ID to update my database and the value of the string for conditional statement purposes. Since WordPress has its own way to work with ajax, here is the code I have to try to test if it does what I want.

**Jquery - custom-js.js:**

```
$(function() {
        $(".deal-vote-button").click(function(){
            var prodID = $(this).attr('productID');
            var voteType = $(this).attr('id');

            $.ajax({
                url: customajaxscript.ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{
                    action: 'productvote',
                    id: prodID,
                    productvote: voteType
                },
                success: function( response ){
                    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                },
                error: function( error ){
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**PHP - custom-functions.php:**

```
/* Custom AJAX functions */
function my_ajax_resource() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom-js.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'my-jquery', 'customajaxscript', 
    array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_ajax_resource');

/* AJAX function for voting system */
function productvote(){
    $productID = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
    $productVoteType = isset($_POST['productvote']) ? $_POST['productvote'] : null;
    echo $productVoteType; // Could be echo "test" or anything else for testing purposes.
    die(); 
}
```

Here is my problem. If I try to `echo` anything containing a letter, I get an error in the response. If I `echo` numbers such as `432432`, `123` or `3`, I get the alert with the response, meaning the code worked. My questions are:

1 - What is wrong with my code causing an error when I `echo` a string containing anything but a number?

2 - If I want to retrieve the data from `$_POST` and associate it in two different variables, is the method I am using correct?

3 - I seem to get a double alert popup when I execute the code, what could be causing that?

Please note that I have no previous experience with JSON and AJAX in WordPress, therefore, it's all new to me.

Comment: Your jQuery ajax request configuration defines dataType as json, so it expects json response. It works for number because integers are valid json. Try `echo json_encode("test");` It will produce `"test"` instead of echoing `test`

Comment: Thanks! it worked